# add_Click does not execute code within block

Tags: powershell

When trying to execute code or update values within a variable inside of the add_Click block, it does not work. I'm not sure if I am doing something incorrectly. Moreover, the statement I have following the code sees the variable as nonexistent.

```
$Button1.add_Click({$authEvent = $true
    $Form.Close() })
$Button2.add_Click({$authEvent = $false
    $Form.Close()
                  })
```

This should update the `$authEvent` variable depending on which button is clicked. As well as closing the form.

Comment: Where is the $authEvent variable coming from? Does it need to be a global variable? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors. It's coming from within the function that this code is in, so it shouldn't need to be a global variable should it?  I tested the variable with an if statement and it looks like the block is not updating the variables. It's fulfilling the $Form.Close(), but not the variables. I'll try it with global vars and let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check where your $authEvent variable is coming from and assign it as a global variable if needed (`$Global:authEvent`)

Note that you only need to use the $Global: option when first declaring the variable. So it should be used like this:

```
$global:authEvent = $null

$Button1.add_Click({
    $authEvent = $true
    $Form.Close() 
})
$Button2.add_Click({
    $authEvent = $false
    $Form.Close()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to I.T Delinquent I've figured out this issue. It appears that the block actually does require a global variable(not sure why it does.) Therefore, I declared the global var at the beginning of the script and from there we had success.

```
$global:authEvent = $null

$Button1.add_Click({$global:authEvent = $true
$Form.Close() })
$Button2.add_Click({$global:authEvent = $false
$Form.Close()
})
```